# MongoDB Query does not return expected results

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm using Python. I send datetime.utcnow() to my MongoDB.
What is wrong with my code:

```
deltaTime = timedelta(minutes=1)

s.find({"status" : "pending",
        "$and" : [{"time" :  {"$lt" :  datetime.utcnow()}},
                  {"time" :  {"$gt" :  datetime.utcnow() - deltaTime }}
                 ]
       }, page=0 , perpage=15 )
```

but it doesn't work.

and the same query in MongoDb does not work either:

```
db.s.find(
{"status" : "pending"  ,
        "$and" :
                [
                  {"time" :  {"$lt" : ISODate("2014-06-05 06:59:31.442Z")  }   }
                  ,
                  {"time" :  {"$gt" : ISODate("2014-06-05 05:59:31.442Z") }   }
                ]
}
```

)

MongoDB says "Script executed successfully but there is no result to show" 
I have records in between! but there is no result, I also have tried the MongoDB query without ISODate() and still there is no result!

Comment: Can you show how you import datetime? Like `import datetime` or `from datetime import *` or just what?

Comment: from datetime import datetime,timedelta

Comment: According to the example: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#documents it uses the datetime class within the datetime package: `datetime.datetime`

Comment: Yes, he seems to have done the proper import of that.

Comment: Does this code fail silently or is there any kind of message?  Was the data written to the database from python or something else, like nodeJS/meteor ?

Comment: Are `page` and `perpage` valid? Should that not be `skip` and `limit`. Not to mention the `$and` is not required as it is implied `{ $gt: "",  $lt: "" }`

Comment: getting stormy.  may need to run.

Comment: The data are written to database from Python "datetime.utcnow()" and the "time" in MongoDB is the same as Python "datetime.utcnow()"

Comment: I simulated the data and ran the same query on the field of type int instead of date. And that worked. The query seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by the following query:

```
db.s.find(
       {
       "status" : "Pending"  
       ,
       "time" :  {
                  "$gt" : ISODate("2014-06-05 06:01:29.397069") , 
                  "$lt" : ISODate("2014-06-05 07:01:29.397069")
                 } 
       }
       )
```

and the "$and" have not worked for me in this case.